# XRDP: How to get remote terminal services without local user login?

Tags: remote-access

I just installed xrdp (remote desktop) and I realise it works great, except 1 problem. When the machine reboots I have to redo the local user login on the machine to start the service.

Ideally I'd like to just have the login screen show up meanwhile a process runs the service in the background. I'd like to disconnect the mouse and keyboard and leave it running so i can connect to it when necessary, not needing the keyboard and mouse every time the machine reboots. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I'm using ubuntu 10.10

Comment: I will set up a 10.10 VM to test this since I've never used XRDP on Ubuntu (only on CentOS), but in CentOS, XRDP runs as a service, and once you set that service to be enabled on bootup, you simply have to power on the machine, and it'll run headless, and you can RDP in. We have some servers that are virtualized on XEN that we connect to in this manner. I'll test on 10.10 for you to see if it'll work this way and I'll answer back if nobody answers before me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question, but I created an Ubuntu 10.10 virtual machine, and simply installed XRDP with the command `sudo apt-get install xrdp`. Once installed, it correctly set up the service to autostart, so I simply powered on the machine, didn't log into the local console, and I was able to initiate an RDP connection to the machine.

Did you install XRDP from the package manager as I outlined above, or did you install it some other way (such as building from source)?

Also, please remember that Ubuntu 10.10 will be end-of-life very soon and all updates and support will end.

Comment: I did this as well (that install command) and I am using Terminal Services Client to connect over to that machine and still its not connecting. That machine was updated from way back from like version 8 or 9 into version 10.10 (after serveral upgrades). I like ubuntu 10.10 its only using about 380mb ram. I think i'm going to format and try a new install, if thats what I have to do

Comment: thank you for doing all that. at least i know it can work on a fresh install